# Query OldValue/NewValue from CaseHistory via GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I try to query CaseHistory by CaseId via GraphQL.
I get such errors for the fields OldValue and NewValue:

> Validation error of type FieldUndefined: Field 'NewValue' in type 'CaseHistory' is undefined @ 'uiapi/query/CaseHistory/edges/node/NewValue

When I query the object via REST API, I am able to get the values for the two fields, but not in GraphQL.
The fields exist ob the object for sure - it's a standard object.
What do I wrong?

When I delete the fields OldValue and NewValue, my GraphQL query works.
My query with the two fields looks like:

```
query queryCase {
    uiapi {
        query {
            CaseHistory(
                where: {
                    CaseId: { eq: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
                }
            ) {
                edges {
                    node {
                        Id,
                        IsDeleted { value }
                        CaseId { value }
                        CreatedById { value }
                        CreatedDate { value }
                        Field { value }
                        OldValue { value }
                        NewValue { value }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CaseHistory is not in the list of supported objects (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_all_supported_objects.htm?_ga=2.193092654.263527894.1703756144-1514154647.1703756144). But there is a comment on the page: "This list might not reflect the latest object support."

You can find the details for the object via API:
GET /services/data/v58.0/ui-api/object-info/CaseHistory

And so I found out, the field names I need are OldvalString and NewvalString.